# jQuery clone method not working the way I want to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to clone each `div` tag to each `li` tag that has a `ul` tag in it:

```
<div id="drop-banner-wrap">
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-1" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-1.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">first</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-2" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-2.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">second</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-3" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-3.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">third</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-4" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-4.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">fourth</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-5" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-5.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">fifth</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-6" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-6.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">sixth</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-7" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-7.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">seventh</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-8" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-8.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">eighth</div>
</div>
```

Here's the navigation structure:

```
<div id="nav-wrap">
    <ul id="nav" class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">District Info</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./">Board of Education</a> </li>
        <li><a href="./">Departments</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="./">Schools</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Staff</a></li>
        <li><a href="./">Quick Links</a></li>
    </ul><!-- /#nav -->
</div><!-- /#nav-wrap -->
```

For example, the `div` with the class `drop-banner-1` should be cloned inside the navigation link District Info because it has a `ul` tag inside of it and it's the first one that has a `ul` tag inside. Then, the `div` with the class `drop-banner-2` should be cloned inside the navigation link Departments because it has a `ul` tag inside of it and it's the second.

Here's my code:

```
$('#drop-banner-wrap div').each(function(){
    var whichDiv = $(this).index();
    var whichNav = $('#nav>li').eq(whichDiv);
    $(this).eq(whichNav).clone(true,true).prependTo('#nav li').find('ul');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where should the cloned div appear within the list? What's an example of the resultant HTML?

Comment: The cloned div should be right before the li tags inside the UL.
#nav > li > ul > div should be here

Comment: But that would be invalid HTML. Only an `<li>` element can be a child of a `<ul>`

Comment: It's okay. I just need to put each of them inside each li tag that has a ul tag inside it

Comment: What is `$(this).eq(whichNav)` supposed to be?` `$(this)` is the current element of the `.each()` loop. Why are you indexing it with `.eq()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want this:

```
$('#drop-banner-wrap div').each(function(i) {
  $(this).clone(true, true).insertBefore($('#nav>li>ul').prev().eq(i));
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/eue1dvdz/1/)**

When you traverse with each you have access to a built-in index argument so you don't need to create a separate variable for that. Next, you want to select the list `#nav>li>ul`, not the list item `#nav>li`, with the index from `.each()` via `eq(i)`.

Comment: https://s4.postimg.io/5fgje31jv/Capture.png

This code cloned the div to the wrong section. It should be inside the ul tag but before all the li tags.

Please check the image I posted

Comment: You can't do that. As I stated above that's invalid HTML and virtually every browser will try and correct that by re-arranging your elements.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#drop-banner-wrap div').each(function(){
            var whichDiv = $(this).index();
            var whichNav = $('#nav>li>ul').eq(whichDiv); 
            $cloneddiv=$(this).clone(true,true);
            $cloneddiv.prependTo($(whichNav));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop-banner-wrap">
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-1" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-1.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">first</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-2" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-2.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">second</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-3" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-3.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">third</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-4" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-4.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">fourth</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-5" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-5.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">fifth</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-6" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-6.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">sixth</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-7" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-7.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">seventh</div>
    <div class="drop-banner drop-banner-8" style="background:url('_assets_/images/drop-8.jpg') center center no-repeat;background-size;cover">eighth</div>
</div>

<div id="nav-wrap">
                        <ul id="nav" class="clearfix">
                            <li><a href="./">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./">District Info</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="./">Board of Education</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="./">Departments</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="./">Dropdown link here</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="./">Schools</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./">Community</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./">Staff</a></li>
                            <li><a href="./">Quick Links</a></li>
                        </ul><!-- /#nav -->
                    </div><!-- /#nav-wrap -->
```

Comment: Sorry was testing something & posted before complete :)